# RGL help axes color

Tags: r, rgl

I am drawing a 3d mdsplot with the rgl package. I would like to know how can I change the color of the axes,labels and titles from black to white?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `r3dDefaults` to set new defaults.  But be aware that white is a bad colour for axes unless you ask for it not to be "lit"; you might want to turn off lighting just for the axes, rather than the whole plot as in this example:

```
r3dDefaults$bg$color <- "gray"
r3dDefaults$material$color <- "white"
r3dDefaults$material$lit <- FALSE
plot3d(rnorm(10), rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
```